# Simulating keyboard input from bash script

Tags: bash, gnu-screen

I have a simple bash script running few programs in `screen` like:

```
#!/bin/bash
program1
program2
program3
```

*<Here I need to simulate **Ctrl+A : hardcopy -h logfile** in bash script>*:

```
Programm4
```

But for my case `xdotool` does not work as well as `expect`. The problem is that I can't start logging screen output at the moment when `screen` is started, but I need to hardcopy all the output printed previously on that `screen` after `program3` is finished without manually inputing `Ctrl+A ...`

Comment: Have you considered using tmux (which has a more official/well-supported mechanism for programatically injecting commands where you don't need to fake keyboard input) instead of screen?

Comment: (honestly, I'm not convinced without hearing the reasoning that there's a good reason to use _either_ tmux or screen).

Comment: on the server I'm currently working ```tmux``` is not 1. installed 2. allowed to install (actually I don't know why but whatever)

Comment: I need to use ```screen``` because the thing that I'm doing... I need to start multiple screens and run bash scripts that are processing different data. ```screen``` is needed because other users from different countries should be able to connect to this screens and see what's happening

Comment: Next question: _Why_ do you need terminal emulation at all, instead of just having your stdout tee'd to a logfile more conventionally? (Is it because the output contains terminal control characters? -- there are other ways to manage that if so).

Comment: If folks just need to _see_ what's happening, why simulate a tty for that instead of just letting them tail a logfile? You can have as many `tail`s running as you need.

Comment: terminal emulation is needed because sometimes they (I) need to input some other commands during programs running and that's why I need to log what's happening on screen and not just tee stdout of programs

Comment: my English is not perfect so I'm sorry for possible mistakes

Answer (score 0):

The following script writes only the output of the first three *echo* commands but neither what came before nor the last *echo* into *~/tmp/programs123.log*:

```
#!/bin/bash
screen -p0 -X clear           # Clear the scrollback buffer
screen -p0 -X scrollback 0    
screen -p0 -X scrollback 100  # Set it to a manageable size
echo "1111"
echo "2222"
echo "3333"
screen -p0 -X hardcopy -h ~/tmp/programs123.log
echo "4444"
```

Adjust the size of the scrollback buffer as needed (currently set to 100).